# How do I use a static variable inside a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Cls:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.counter += 1
    def count(self):
        return self.counter
```

I'm learning python, what I want to have is a static counter that counts the number of times the class has been instantiated, but every time I create an instance `counter` gets recreated and `count()` function always returns 1.
I want something that in java would look like this

```
public class Cls {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private String name;
    public Cls(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        counter ++;
    }
    public static int count(){
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use Cls as a class name...cls is a reserved word in Python...just saying.

Comment: @ma3oun `cls` is not reserved, it's merely idiomatic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two ways to access a class attribute: you can either access it directly on a class, or you can read it through `self` (but not rebind it). Accessing a class attribute through `self` won't work if there is already a value set directly on the instance so you would normally try to use the class to access a class attribute.

```
class Cls:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Cls.counter += 1
    def count(self):
        return Cls.counter
```

When you write `self.counter += 1` this is a shorthand for `self.counter = self.counter + 1` and as with any other binding through `self` it sets an instance attribute.

This can be useful if you want a default value for instance attributes, you can set them as class attributes and then just update them in the instances which want different values, but to avoid confusion you probably want to avoid using `self` at all when accessing class attributes.

You can also consider making the `count` method into a class method and moving the increment into another method:

```
@classmethod
def increment(cls):
    cls.counter += 1

@classmethod
def count(cls):
    return cls.counter
```

if you do that then each subclass will have its own independent counter. That may or may not be what you want here. The `cls` parameter here is the class that was actually instantiated, this can be useful if you can a whole class hierarchy, or even just a base class `CountsInstances` where you can put this code once and reuse it with multiple independent counters.

Decorating each function with `@staticmethod` will give you something close to the Java code:

```
class Cls:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.increment()

    @staticmethod
    def increment():
        Cls.counter += 1

    @staticmethod
    def count():
        return Cls.counter
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the difference between a class vs. static method here—the relevant bit being that a class method optionally lets subclasses each keep their own counter, while a static method forces them all to share a counter. Then again, you’ve already explained quite a bit, so maybe that extra info would just overload the OP? Not sure, but it’s your answer so I don’t have to be sure. :)

Comment: @abarnert I expanded it slightly but I'll let your comment lead on that: there's a huge can of worms that could be opened here once you get into inheritance.

Comment: I think you found a great balance of raising the issue but not getting bogged down in it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Cls.

```
class MyClass:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.counter += 1  # this creates an instance variable counter 
                           # thats initialized by counter if you do not set it
                           # it is NOT shared between instances, but specific to each
```

Instead you should increment the static variable:

```
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        MyClass.counter += 1  # this increments the static class variable
```

If you fix

```
    @staticmethod
    def count():
        return MyClass.counter
```

this way, you can still call count() on instances as well as directly on the class.

```
t = MyClass("some")
print( MyClass.count() )  # fine

t1 = MyClass("other")
print( t.count() )        # only allowed if prefix the method with @staticmethod
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

See [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python) for further infos.

Comment: I guess the explanation would be more understandable and helpfull if u mention how final class looks like...

Comment: @AviC note sure what you mean. The fix is to change `self.counter += 1` to `MyClass.counter += 1` so the CLASS-counter variable is incremented - not the INSTANCE-copy of that value. I provided the changed method.  The change using `@staticmethod` on `count()` makes it clear that this accesses the CLASS variable. If you keep using `def count(self): return MyClass.counter` you "suggest" that `count` is a method on the instance of a class - but you return the class-variable and never use the `self` to access anything of the instance - so it is confusing and a bit cheaty.